# Using *OpenMP* together with X11, SFML or OpenGL

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, x11, sfml

I am working on a thread visualization tool. The idea is to see each thread working in parallel through an image filter.

Lets say that we have the rgba values of a 512x512 image. I will apply the filter on these values and I want to see the result *in real time*. So if we share the work on two threads, say thread A gets the upper half of the work on the image and thread B the bottom part, I would like to see the image "changing" from 2 different places at the same time when the program is running.

I am able to do so without OpenMP (in other words, without multi-threading), but when I use OpenMP, I always run into problems with the graphical stuff that I am using to plot the pixels on the screen, like X11 or SFML.

**My question is:** Is it possible to use OpenMP to generate multiple threads able to set pixels on a window handled by SFML or X11 (maybe even OpenGL, although the first 2 options are better) in parallel (also in "real time")?

I know that SFML has a way to work with threads, but they aren't generated by OpenMP, so that doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT**: Here is the fragment of code that I'm using:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
            omp_set_lock(&windowLock);
            XSetForeground(d, &(DefaultGC(d, s)), pixelMatrix[i][j][0] << 16 | pixelMatrix[i][j][1] << 8 | pixelMatrix[i][j][2]);
            XDrawPoint(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), j, i);
            omp_unset_lock(&windowLock);
        }
    }
```

Using this piece of code I achieve what I want, but I am using a Mutex here in order to block two threads plotting pixels at the same time, and that is something that I don't want.

At first I thought that the problem was with using multiple threads, but now I believe that the problem is something regarding the way X11 sets the color in the function XSetForeground (maybe it is using global variables to hold the color?).

If I don't use the Mutex I end up with an image with pixels with a wrong color, because the threads use the color set by another thread...

I want to multiple thread set pixels on my window without having to use a mutex.

Thanks again.

Comment: How have you implemented your OpenMP pragma statements around your loop that manipulates the image?

Comment: So far I am trying with a simple #pragma omp parallel, creating 2 threads right before the first for (the column pixel for). Inside this for I check the thread number to determine which part of the image should it apply the filter.

Comment: Please show the code. This is the way the sequential code is written that will tell whether it can be parallelised with OpenMP simply.

Comment: This is certainly possible. I wrote a ray tracer in OpenCL which ran on two GPUs and one CPU and rendered to the screen at several FPS (depending on the complexity of the scene).  For example GPU0 rendered the first 45%, GPU1 the next 45%, and  CPU0 the last 10% of the frame but actually I adjusted these numbers dynamically based on the previous frame...maybe if you showed a bit of code we could understand what you mean by "when I use OpenMP, I always run into problems with the graphical stuff"

Comment: The problem with OpenMP is that its always difficult to say where the split is going to occur in terms of what will be calculated on which core.  Is your row loop your outer loop, and your column loop your inner?  That would explain (at least partially) why you are seeing what you are seeing.  Usually images are stored in RAM such that they are row after row, so trying to put the OpenMP parallelizer statement in front of the column loop might create interesting results due to how the data is stored, and how it will be called in at runtime!

Comment: Thank you all that tried to help. After trying a lot of stuff I "discovered"  that it is indeed possible to use OpenMP together with X11, but I still am unable to do what I want. However, I believe that my problem is due to the way X11 implemented two functions...
I will edit my question and give a code example and more explanation about the problem with X11 rn.